# Livewire flash message appears only once when action if performed

Tags: laravel-livewire

hello everyone i just wanna know how to make a flash message appears everytime when an action is performed.
I have an categories table in my blade and at the end of every row there is a delete button when i press it the action is performed successfully and my flash message appears as a Popup (SweetAlert2) but when i delete another row the delete function runs successfully but the popup doesn't appear again.

In my blade

```
@if(session()->has('process-error')) 
<script>
    Swal.fire(
        'Error',
        '{{ session('process-error') }}',
        'error'
    )
</script>
@endif
@if(session()->has('process-success'))
    <script>
        Swal.fire(
            'Success',
            '{{ session('process-success') }}',
            'success'
        )
    </script>
@endif
```

in my component

```
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $categoriesService = CategoriesService::deleteCategory($id);

        if(!$categoriesService)
        {
            // RETURN AN ERROR MESSAGE
            session()->flash('process-error' , 'Failed to delete the category');
            return;
        }

        // RETURN A SUCCESS MESSAGE
        session()->flash('process-success' , 'Category deleted successfully!');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have installed Swall you don't need to show it through session()->flash(). You can dispatch a js event and capture it like

```
if(!$categoriesService)
{
   // RETURN AN ERROR MESSAGE
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('process-swall',['type' => 'error']);
   return;
}

// RETURN A SUCCESS MESSAGE
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('process-swall' ,['type' => 'success']);
}

 //in script section

<script>
   window.addEventListener('process-swall', event => {
       let type = event.detail.type;
       let message = type === 'success' ? 'Category deleted successfully!' : 'Failed to delete the category';
       let camelCaseType = type === 'success' ? 'Success' : 'Error';
       Swal.fire(
            camelCaseType,
            message,
            type
        )
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you are better off dispatching a browser-event and listening for that in JavaScript, rather than using sessions. Sessions can be a bit tricky between requests, since Livewire is in effect a stateless API.

When using `dispatchBrowserEvent()`, you can pass in data as the second argument, which will be available in the `event.detail` property of the event.

```php
public function delete($id)
{
    $categoriesService = CategoriesService::deleteCategory($id);

    if (!$categoriesService) {
        $swalData = [
            'type' => 'error',
            'title' => 'Error',
            'message' => 'Failed to delete category',
        ];
    } else {
        $swalData = [
            'type' => 'success',
            'title' => 'Success',
            'message' => 'Sucessfully deleted category',
        ];
    }
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('notify-swal', $swalData);
}
```

And then - once in your blade (would suggest maybe in your layout, that way its reusable across all components), add a listener for that event.

```html
@once
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('notify-swal', function(e) {
            let data = e.detail;
            let title = data.title;
            let message = data.message;
            let type = data.type; 
            
            Swal.fire(title, message, type);
        });
    </script>
@endonce
```

Comment: that's work tho thanks for ur help as well.